# 'there exists...' statements

Tags: logic, semantics, quantification

When using Logic, we often verbalize existentially quantified statements as 'there exists an x such that...' but why do we say 'there exists a number x such that...' (in our domain is the reals) why do we say 'there exists *A number*' when we can have more values of x (or more objects that satisfy) the predicate, the wording seems to imply there is just one acceptable value or object that satisfies the predicate.

Comment: "Or" has essentially the same issue: in math or logic , "P or Q" means what in normal English would be "P or Q or both". It's the same issue because exists x.p(x), for a finite set of candidates x in {a1, a2, a..., an} means p(a1) or p(a2) or ... or p(an).

Answer (score 1):

By convention the statement "there exists x such that ..." is a shorthand for

> there exists at least one x such that ...

Comment: “How many months in the year have 28 days?”  “All of them.”  Sometimes in English an existential qualifier is taken to mean a maximum as well as a minimum, but sentential logic does not have that ambiguity.  

“I used to do drugs. I still do, but I used to, too.”
― Mitch Hedberg

Comment: @Michael Lorton In mathematics the existential quantifier means the minimum.

Comment: — yes, that was my point: English has the ambiguity but math does not.  Obviously, mathematicians do everything they can to drive out ambiguity, that is their job.  There are linguists trying to accomplish the same thing for a (constructed) spoken language, but I don’t know how they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The specific numerical correlations over the basic standard quantifiers are:

> 1. ~∃ → *x* = 0
> 2. ∃ → *x* ≥ 1
> 3. ~∀ → *x* < max(*x*)
> 4. ∀ → *x* = max(*x*)

The term "max(*x*)" can be switched out with *U*, where *U* is a universe of discourse (the maximum set under ambient consideration, or a proper class). So if with Frege you characterize the unrestricted *U* as "anti-zero," you can characterize (3) and (4) in the above list as correlating a "number" with the universal quantifier.

That the existential quantifier has its ambiguous upwards conditions of satisfaction is due to its being an interpretation of "some" (and its historical, e.g. Greek Aristotelian, cognates), which usually can cover anywhere from one to all of its possible referents. Note that you could just as well say:

> 5. ∃ → x > 0

And with only ordinals in play, that's equal to (2). Introducing fractional or other surreal-numbered options, e.g. for some quantifier ∃<sup>!</sup> → 0 < x < 1, is probably something that has been done in one of the myriad logic theories out there (I'd bet on fuzzy logic first), though I haven't seen this introduction or its method carried through specifically anywhere.

EDIT: Another thing worth looking into would be [plural quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/). Your puzzlement over referring to the existence of a single "number of *x*" rather than referring to plurally existent *x* reminded me of that topic.